# How can I run the discontiuned NetMeeting on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, conferencing, netmeeting

Microsoft discontinued NetMeeting a while ago and it is no longer included in Vista or Windows 7. I have read that there is a hot fix to get it working on Vista, but is there such a thing for Windows 7?

I know there are alternatives available, but I was wondering if anyone has managed to it working on Windows 7? I am just interested in running the client component of NetMeeting, to connect to a meeting hosted on a Windows XP machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discussion on SevenForums [Netmeeting replacement in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-internet/3837-netmeeting-replacement-windows-7-a.html) has this to say,

> Does Netmeeting work in Win7?
>   No it doesn't, nor does the "Vista compatible" version of Netmeeting. Unless something is offered to replace it, Windows Meeting Spaces (or whatever it is called in Vista now) isn't even included in the Win7 beta, or at least I can't find it if it is.

But, do read it up once.

---

There is also a [Wikipedia note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_NetMeeting#Discontinued) on the same.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it with XP Mode?

Answer (score 1):

We have tried it and it does work in XP mode (http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) but it is not something we really want our users to have.

Answer (score 1):

yes Netmeeting does work in Win 7 but I can't use the Sharing function (it was grey out and can't be selected).  Other user who can continue to share their apps/desktop.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Restore down" (i.e. un-maximize) the VM window to get access to the tools menu
2. Select "Disable integration Features" from the "tools" menu
3. (Re)maximize the VM window
4. (Re)launch Netmeeting only after previous steps were complete
5. (Re)join any call you were in where you wanted to share an app or your desktop
6. Share like you did before Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

For support purposes: Microsoft's Offer Remote Assistance is better than Netmeeting.

It can be configured to allow admins to assist without issue and allows users to view while support is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Netmeeting works in Windows 7.  Here's how, assuming that you are connecting to a private network.

- Install XP virtual machine and run it
- In the title bar, `Tools->Settings->Networking`

  - Change the adapter from NAT to your installed hardware network adapter
- Setup VPN in the XP VM, run it, and connect to your private network
- Enable the windows firewall in the XP VM (optional but recommended)
- `Start->run->conf`

  - Configure netmeeting